# Jquery Get Reqeust Not Displaying Data

Tags: php, jquery

Ok, I have two pages. getprofilecomment.php and getprofilecomment.js. The get getprofilecomment.php is functioning, but the getprofilecomment.js is not working for some reason. It is not displaying any content. The div id is correct. Here is the code:

```
$(function()
{
var userId = $(#userid).val();

$.ajax({
  url: "api/getprofilecomment.php",
  method: "GET",
  data: userId,
  cache: false,
  success: function(comment){
       $(#usercommentdiv).apprend('<li>' + comment.user_name + ':' + comment.profile_comment + ',' + comment.time_added + '</li>');
  }
});
});
```

Once again, the json_encode is echoing the content successfully to the page.

```
<?php
include ("../db/database.php");
include ("../classes/profilecommentclass.php");

session_start();
$profileCommentHandler = new ProfileComment($db);
$userId = $_GET['userId'];
$profileComment = $profileCommentHandler->getComment($userId);
echo json_encode($profileComment,  JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
?>
```

Comment: did you tried to `console.log(comment)` to check what exactly returns on success?

Comment: please remove the data and try this in url  `api/getprofilecomment.php?userId=${userId}`

Answer (score 0):

Hi you are missing id (usercommentdiv) in quotes,

```
success: function(comment){
       $('#usercommentdiv').apprend('<li>' + comment.user_name + ':' + comment.profile_comment + ',' + comment.time_added + '</li>');
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for providing this invaluable feedback!

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot!...I had "apprend" instead of "append" for anything looking at this question with the same or similar problem.